# Reporting Services is slow

Tags: c#, performance, reportingservices-2005

OK, I have a report in Reporting Services 2005 backed by SQL Server 2005.

I use some C# code to generate 10 records.  Maybe 12 columns.  There are only 6500 records in the table.

I record those records to the database and then simply display them.  So the Reporting Server isn't doing any calculations or anything intense that I can tell.

The records were created in the DB at 3:57PM today.  It's 4:11PM now.  It's consistently taking 15 - 30 MINUTES to run.

Now, the server hardware is pretty good (12 gigs, 4 cores, etc).  BUT it is under pretty heavy load.  So I'm guessing that is a part of the problem.

But is there anything I can do to help speed up this process?  It sits on the "Report is being generated" circle forever.

Thanks.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention I do have indexes setup on the column RS uses to fetch.

Comment: Sorry about the lame subject.  I was frustrated and SLOOW more accurately reflected my mood.  LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.  We moved to a much faster server.  We found that the existing server was being brought down by other services.